# Swiper slider not working as expected with loop: true in Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I am facing the problem on my website, the loop of the slider was not working. The link of my website is [link](https://www.indiaaffiliatesummit.in) ,Under testimonial section slider loop was not working. This website is built in Wordpress and I am using the NRG carousel slider item.
I am using NRG carousel slider in my Wordpress theme.

Please help me, How I can run loop of this slider?

url:- https://www.indiaaffiliatesummit.in

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: In console, there is an error " D.snapGrid[(g + 1)] is undefined", look into that

Comment: you are using two slider with same class. just use different class for sliders

Comment: In the console, I get this error.                                                                         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined
    at Swiper.D.swipeNext (idangerous.swiper.min.js:15)
    at idangerous.swiper.min.js:15

Comment: At the top only one slider is available. so its showing the error

Comment: @George, But when i use only one slider, it gives the same problem

Comment: yes. you dont need to use `loop: loopVar,` for top slider.

Comment: @George, I have removed the loop from first slider, but the loop of testimonials was not working.

Comment: just use different class for testimonials slider

Comment: @George, Can you please suggest me any free Wordpress carousel slider ,in which loop was working fine?

Comment: Swiper slider is fine. I was worked more than 2 slider on same page.

Comment: @George loop of Main slider in home page was working fine, But testimonial loop was not working,  I am using this slider on another page.   Url:-   https://www.indiaaffiliatesummit.in/testing_agenda/

Comment: shortcode is displaying in your test page. slider not displaying

Comment: @George, I am sorry for this, can you please check again.

Comment: please create a fiddle?